# Merge two SQL tables with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have start to learn SQL now and now my question:
Look at my uploaded image and say me how I can filter all product categorys with the id_product = 45 and my return value is 45-3,45-2 and the row 1 from product groups.

Again: I will have ALL product_groups rows (1,2,3) and the related id_category(product_category) with the id_product = 45.

It's not easy to explain, sry for my bad English..

[image: The two SQL Tables]

Here is a SQL-Query who gives all rows with id from product_groups and id_product = 45 but NOT the id = 3 with empty values :-(

```
SELECT 
  id, title, multiplayer, id_product 
FROM 
  product_category 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN products_groups ON 
  rg_product_category.id_category = products_groups.id 
WHERE 
  product_category.id_product = '45' OR 
  product_category.id_product IS NULL AND products_groups.type = 'Game';
```

thanks for all help

Comment: for one it looks like you are missing parenthesis around  product_category.id_product IS NULL AND products_groups.type = 'Game'

Comment: Does product group 3 have type 'Game'?  Also, consider flipping your query around.  LEFT joins are generally considered easier to read than RIGHT joins.

Comment: Yes, the column type of product group has the type 'game'. Look at the picture :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what you want: You want to list all product_groups, with null values if there's no match. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  id, title, multiplayer, id_product 
FROM  products_groups
LEFT JOIN product_category
  ON product_category.id_category = products_groups.id 
  AND product_category.id_product = '45'
WHERE products_groups.type = 'Game';
```

Comment: Hey, this query has not the value id="3" from the table "product_groups". I need id="3" in my result table. The rest of the query is correct.

Comment: @Bohemian: Reverse the `FROM products_groups LEFT JOIN product_category`